# jQuery addClass method does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a class to a div when it is a specific time of the day. My jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var hour = d.getHours();
    console.log(hour)
    if(hour >= 18 && hour <= 4) {
        $("#time").addClass("night");
    }
})
```

The problem is that the above code does nothing. If I try to add the class manually in the div like `<div id="time" class="night"></div>`, it works.

- My style sheet is linked correctly
- jQuery is installed correctly and works with other functions
- Script.js is linked correctly to the HTML

Any ideas, why is it not working?

Comment: Can the condition ever by true `hour >= 18 && hour <= 4`?

Comment: It is true. I have console logged the output. See there.

Comment: How can a number be greater than 18 and at the same time be less than 4?

Comment: This condition would never work lol

Comment: I think the condition you want is `hour <= 18 && hour >= 4`

Comment: Oh, my bad, Sorry. Well, I want the night class after 18 hours (6PM) and before 4 AM

Comment: @KumarPriyansh use "or" instead of "and" comparison.

Comment: `(hour <= 4 || hour >= 18)` gives you any hour before or equal to 4AM, or after or equal to 6PM

Comment: i think its a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` never works because no number is greater than 18 and at the same time less than 4. You have to change your `if` from

```
if(hour >= 18 && hour <= 4) {
```

to

```
if(hour >= 18 || hour <= 4) {
```